# How to prevent a file from being read and written by two threads

Tags: flutter, dart

One of my threads is writing multiple files to the folder

Another thread of mine is keeping asking if there is a file in the folder, and upload it if there is a file

How can I not read the file being written

Comment: Write files to filename.tmp and after writing is done, you rename the file. Your other thread should then ignore events from files ending with .tmp.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.